# Firebase Firestore: query list of users liked my profile

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building Flutter app with Firebase Firestore. I'm trying to implement likes feature bug faced some platform limitations.

I have a collection `users`. 
Each user has `likedUsers` collection where I store `uid`s of liked users. Also each user has 'likedBy' collection where I store `uid`s of other users liked current user.

Firestore is not allowing to run collection group query, so I can't get all users that have `uid` of current user in their `likedUsers` collection.

What I can do is only to get list of user `uid`s from 'likedBy' collection of current user and get users one by one like this:

```
final QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _db
    .collection(FirebaseContract.USERS_COL)
    .document(uid)
    .collection(User.LIKED_BY_COL)
    .getDocuments();


querySnapshot.documents.forEach(
  (DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    _db.collection(FirebaseContract.USERS_COL).document(snapshot.documentID).get().then(
      (DocumentSnapshot document) {
        print(document[User.NAME]);
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Is there any more elegant, time and cost efficient solution for this problem than this?

Answer (score 1):

For now, Firestore mobile API doesn't handle queries by arrays of References (whether of collections or documents) :

> Retrieving a list of collections is not possible with the mobile/web client libraries. You should only look up collection names as part of administrative tasks in trusted server environments. If you find that you need this capability in the mobile/web client libraries, consider restructuring your data so that subcollection names are predictable.

[Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

This means that the only way to get an array of collections from their references is to enumerate the way you do it.